# CLP(FD): solution number count speedup

Tags: prolog, clpfd, clpb

I'm working with the following SWI-Prolog version: `SWI-Prolog version 9.1.2 for x86_64-linux`.

I'm trying to count the number of valid solutions using Prolog and the CLP(FD) module. Currently, to count the number of valid solutions, I'm using the `findall/3` predicate in the following way:

```
findall(1, labeling([max, up, enum], Flat), CountList),
length(CountList, Count),
```

This works, but with a larger number of solutions (> 1.000.000) it starts getting slow. I imagine that's because what I'm essentially doing is generating all of the solutions instead of reasoning it from the valid domain of my variables. I assume that creating a list with million elements in it doesn't help either.

Is there a way of only counting the number of possible solutions to *N* variables in CLP(FD) **without** generating them?

I've tried using the FD set predicates: `fd_set/2` and `fdset_size/2`, and multiply the FD set sizes of all variables. The problem is that the FD set size I get don't account for FD intersection, so the solution count is too high.

I've also tried using the `sat_count/2` predicate from the CLP(B) module, but I was unable to use it properly, since it reasons over boolean variables, while my variables are integers, so from this code:

```
sat_count(+[1|Variables], Count),
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Domain error: `clpb_expr' expected, found `+[1,0,0,2,2,4,6,8,8,10,10,12,14,16,16,18,18,20,22,24,24,26,26,28,30,32,32,34,34,36,38]'
```

So I assume I should convert every variable to a boolean expression, so that the sum of the sat count of those expressions equals to the number of valid solutions I get by using `labeling/2`, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first fix, consider to use an efficient implementation of [`countall/2`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/countall). Currently, good implementations are available in GNU, Scryer, and Trealla.
This alone will give you some of the speed up you are asking for.

```
?- countall(( X in 1..7, Y in 5..9, labeling([],[X,Y]) ), T).
   T = 35.
```

However, this is only an incremental improvement minimizing space consumption and increasing speed by some constant factor only.
A better approach would be to use the labeling option `upto_in/1` which avoids labeling out slackish variables.  Instead, it unifies its argument with the number of solutions like so:

```
?- X in 1..7, Y in 5..9, labeling([upto_in(S)],[X,Y]).
   S = 35, clpz:(X in 1..7), clpz:(Y in 5..9).
?- countall(( X in 1..7, Y in 5..9, X #< Y, labeling([],[X,Y]) ), T).
   T = 29.
?- X in 1..7, Y in 5..9, X #< Y, labeling([upto_in(S)],[X,Y]).
   X = 1, S = 5, clpz:(Y in 5..9)
;  X = 2, S = 5, clpz:(Y in 5..9)
;  X = 3, S = 5, clpz:(Y in 5..9)
;  ... .
?- findall(S, ( X in 1..7, Y in 5..9, X #< Y, labeling([upto_in(S)],[X,Y]) ), Ss), sum_list(Ss, T).
   Ss = [5,5,5,5,4,3,2], T = 29.
```

In case you are interested going into such details even further, consider to
use [Scryer](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog), as the author of SWI's `library(clpfd)` has moved to Scryer with `library(clpz)`.

There might be even further progress, when considering the answer above:

```
?- X in 1..7, Y in 5..9, X #< Y, labeling([upto_in(S)],[X,Y]).
   X = 1, S = 5, clpz:(Y in 5..9)
;  X = 2, S = 5, clpz:(Y in 5..9)
;  X = 3, S = 5, clpz:(Y in 5..9)
;  X = 4, S = 5, clpz:(Y in 5..9)
;  X = 5, S = 4, clpz:(Y in 6..9)
;  X = 6, S = 3, clpz:(Y in 7..9)
;  X = 7, S = 2, clpz:(Y in 8..9).
```

A better way might be to collapse the first 4 answers:

```
?- X in 1..7, Y in 5..9, X #< Y, labeling([betterupto_in(S)],[X,Y]).
   S = 20, clpz:(X in 1..4), clpz:(Y in 5..9) % not implemented
;  X = 5, S = 4, clpz:(Y in 6..9)
;  X = 6, S = 3, clpz:(Y in 7..9)
;  X = 7, S = 2, clpz:(Y in 8..9).
```

Or simply reorder the variables for labeling:

```
?- X in 1..7, Y in 5..9, X #< Y, labeling([upto_in(S)],[Y,X]).
   Y = 5, S = 4, clpz:(X in 1..4)
;  Y = 6, S = 5, clpz:(X in 1..5)
;  Y = 7, S = 6, clpz:(X in 1..6)
;  S = 14, clpz:(X in 1..7), clpz:(Y in 8..9).
```